# C++ - Easily manage potentially infinite instances (bullets for example)

Tags: c++, object

I would like to know if there's an easy way of handling potentially infinite instances of an object, in this case a bullet. As the player in my game can fire continuously as well as there being many enemies on the screen at once there is a high probability there will be over 100 instances of the 'bullet' object, 10x more if I slow bullet speed and increase rate of fire. Do I need to keep them in a dynamic array (std::vector for example) and move them one by one, or is there an easier way that can control them all without severe lag/delay?

Comment: 100 is hardly "infinite".

Comment: Depends how you are going to use them. Need to find one by a specific ID or something? Put them in a `std::map` for `O(1)` lookup time. Need to resize, sort, etc? Put them in a `std::vector`.

Comment: @Cyber: I am sure an `std::map` is `O(log n)`

Comment: My mistake I meant `std::unordered_map`

Comment: @T.C. What I meant is that the system can create as many bullets as the computer can handle (and more), it's just the bullet travel time means there won't probably be more than 100 on screen at a time.

Comment: Estimate how large your bullet object is. Figure out how much memory (your|average) computer has, divide second by first and stop worrying about memory/access speed unless you see in profiler that it is becoming an issue. What you might want to worry about is keeping collision detection fast. You definitely don't want to check collision of everything with everything as it can explode really fast.

Comment: Also you'd want to worry about allocating/deallocating bullet objects: you generally don't want to call `new`/`delete` (as these guys are damn slow) for each new bullet or bullet that hit something, `std::vector` should handle it, though.

Comment: Start with `std::vector` as your default container. Then measure. Then optimize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to iterate through all of bullets and do something with them (like move) then `std::vector` is the best default choice.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a non-missile weapon like a machine gun or pistol, you should reconsider your system of spawning an object for each bullet. The standard way of handling this kind of thing is *raycasting* for each shot, and checking for the first (or multiple) collisions, and handling it straight away (or in some speciality games, on a delay). This is usually accompanied by a muzzle flash of some sort, which completes the illusion.

For missile weapons, you definitely need to spawn objects and keep track of them, as the projectiles are slow enough to be avoided, shot, etc. In this case, use a `std::vector` like Wojtek suggested.

The [Game Dev SE](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) has plenty of useful reads concerning FPS design. Good luck!

Comment: From my limited understanding, raycasting is used in FPS games - I am making a 2D shoot-em-up, like Space Invaders but with more havoc. However the amount of bullets remains high.

Comment: Oh I see, yup then a vector or linked list is the way to go